# Create a Container witch shape is like image(see attached image)

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout

see below image

[image]

I want create a container(or other widget) with custom shape that like same as image.
I don't want create content in that, just shape of that.
This isn't `BorderRadius`, because those sides is curved.(I want create this sides like that image).
I prefer that implemented without `CustomPaint`.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can create that ui with `figma_squircle: ^0.5.3` .

Answer (score 0):

It totally border radius bro just try  The width & height

```
Align(
        child: Container(
          height: 50,
          width: 100,
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40, left: 40, right: 40),
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.green,
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 0.0),
            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(Radius.elliptical(100, 50)),
          ),
          child: Text('     '),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: first of all, this is a Flutter, not a CSS/HTML question. Secondary, that's not a simple radius border.

Comment: Align(
            child: Container(
              height: 50,
              width: 100,
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40, left: 40, right: 40),
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.green,
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 0.0),
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(Radius.elliptical(100, 50)),
              ),
              child: Text('     '),
            ),
          ),

Comment: It should working

Comment: It becomes an oval in small sizes.
And in other sizes, a rectangle with curved corners and perfectly smooth sides is very ugly.
While the sides should be curved relative to the corners

Comment: @OMiShah i answer.

Comment: @Error2.0 i answer.